# enable sharding on all collections existing in a Mongodb database  in one shot

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I have a huge database , which has some 300 collections , I have to enable sharding for each collections , Is there a command to enable sharding on all collections from mongos ,

lets say my db name is abc

I enabled sharding for db like this

```
db.runCommand({"enablesharding" : "abc"})
```

later I need to use

```
db.runCommand( { shardcollection : "collection name", key : { _id : 1 } } )
```

foreach collection ,

so Please suggest and easy way of doing it

Thanks in advance for responding to this post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get all collection names programmatically.

```
db.getCollectionNames().forEach(function(coll_name) {
  db.runCommand( { shardcollection : coll_name, key : { _id : 1 } } )
})
```

Comment: It should work if your original `db.runCommand({shardcollection...` worked. I tested it with `print`.

Comment: It is working but For me it I print db.getlasterror it is showing access denied and use admin , but my db is different , is there any way to preinitialize the db name there , actually it accepts , dbname.collectionname

Comment: Please let me know if you get any way @Sergio Tulentsev

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but you can get alias for a db. `var admin = db.getSiblingDB('admin')`. And then you can run commands on it: `admin.runCommand(...)`.

Comment: Superb , This is what is required , Thank you so much @Sergio Tulentsev

Comment: You can also do `db.adminCommand` instead of `db.getSiblingDB("admin").runCommand`. And remember that the value inside 'shardcollection' is actually the namespace so it's `<database>.<collection>`

Comment: Thank you @GianPaj for some more answers